# Less Convoluted Way of Getting Rid of Odd Nodes in Linked List Python 3

Tags: python, while-loop, linked-list

Below is my function removeOdds that deletes all odd nodes in a Linked List.

```
def removeOdds(myList):
    head=myList
    ptr=head
    counter=1
    while ptr['next']['next']!=None:
        if counter %2 != 0:
            ptr['data'] = ptr['next']['data']
            ptr['next'] = ptr['next']['next']
            counter += 1
        else:
            ptr = ptr['next']
            counter += 1
    counter += 1
    if counter %2 != 0:
        ptr['next'] = None
    return head
```

I was wondering if there is a way for me to delete the last node if it's odd and points to None without me having to exit the while loop.
Just for clarity, my linked lists look like nested dictionaries.
ex.

```
{'data': 9, 'next': {'data': 8, 'next': {'data': 6, 'next': {'data': 5,
'next': {'data': 3, 'next': {'data': 2, 'next': {'data': 1, 'next': 
None}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the loop to while True, move the test for None into the loop, and use break to exit the loop under the appropriate condition, I think you'll find that you don't have to duplicate code outside the loop.